Blender, material color is not showing. Im in Render Preview mode and Checked viewport setting
I am following the doughnut tutorial from Blender Guru and I can not get the color of my objects to change...  Here is a screenshot that shows that I am in the render preview mode, and even checked the viewport setting.
I can get the color to change, if I turn on the node and change the material type to diffuse BSDF instead of the default Principle BSDF.
Im trying to follow the doughnut tutorial though, so any help on how to get the color to change by only following the tutorial would be great, cause I feel like I'm missing something small that is important


Hello and welcome. You tagged your question with Blender Internal Render engine which has been retired with Blender 2.8, but you seem to be using modern versions of Blender. You also failed to mention which render engine you are using.

Did you apply the right material to your mesh?

Hi im not sure about the render engine... I'm working on a clean install, so I am assuming its the default Cycles rendering engine

If i follow the Blender Guru, he just uses Principled BSDF.  When I copy him, my model color renders as red, no matter what color i actually choose.   I can get color to start showing up when i switch it to Diffuse BSDF... But that doesn't explain to me why Principled BSDF would not be showing color correctly

Well i kind of solve the issue, or at least found a workaround.   If i set my IOR to 1, the color for Principled BSDF changes correctly.  As soon as I change it to greater than 1, so like 1.1 it starts to break and not show the right color
